# Catching window state change by custom system buttons

Tags: forms, delphi, winapi, system, message

I'm developing custom system buttons - minimize, maximize and close window. It's working OK, but also I want to catch changing window state for Maximize / Restore down button. For example, when user double click on window title, window maximized and corresponding button should automatically repaint for "Restore down" state.
As I know, there is `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message for Form which notify for window state change. And we can get parent form for button (by `GetParentForm()`). So how to tie it all together? Or maybe you suggests something else?
Button inherits by `TCustomControl`.

Comment: To handle WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, override the Form's virtual `WndProc()` method, or define a `message` handler. See [Using the Windows API Messaging Solution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_Windows_API_Messaging_Solution) in Delphi's documentation for details.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how to do it for form - catch form's message and in message processing repaint button. But I want to create independent button: just drop it to form and it catching changing it's parent form's windows state by itself. But how to do it...

Comment: for what you are asking, you would need to subclass the parent Form's `WindowProc` property, or even the parent Form's `HWND` directly via `SetWindowSubclass()` or `SetWindowLongPtr()`, or just use a message/cbt hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`.